# i got error " Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

Im getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in controller

[controller]

```
fetchGameData() {
  DataModel.getList().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
}
```

[DataModel]

```
export default {
    getList() {
        fetch('URL')
        .then((res) => {
            return Promise.resolve(res.json());
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Fetch Error!!!", err);
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The error is already clear actually. Your function `getList()` does not return anything which is going to be `undefined` in JavaScript. You should return "something" at the end of your function. If you want to use `.then` on the return value of your function, you probably want to return a ["Promise"](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp)

`fetch` function will return a `Promise` anyway. So can simply return that. You can find more info about fetch [here https://javascript.info/fetch](https://javascript.info/fetch)

So a neater alternative would be

```
export default {
    getList() {
        return fetch('URL')
        .then((res) => {
            return Promise.resolve(res.json());
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Fetch Error!!!", err);
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a `promise` to do `.then`

```
export default {
  getList() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch("URL")
        .then((res) => {
          resolve(res.json());
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("Fetch Error!!!", err);
        });
    });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[Service]

```
async function getList() {
      const result = await fetch('URL')
        .then((res) => {
            return Promise.resolve(res.json());
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Fetch Error!!!", err);
        })
      return result.json();
}
```

[controller]

```
fetchGameData() {
  DataModel.getList().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because the `DataModel.getList()` doesn't return a **Promise** so you can have access to Promise `then` chain. All you have to do is to add a return keywork in the getList before the `fetch` function so the `getList` method can return a resolve Promise instead of `undefined`

```
export default {
    getList() {
        return fetch('URL')
            .then((res) => {
                return Promise.resolve(res.json());
            })
            .catch((err) => {
               console.log("Fetch Error!!!", err);
            });
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the promise inside your `getList()` function.

otherwise a function with no return will return undefined.

And this you will have the error "...cant read then of undefined"

your code should be :

```
export default {
getList() {
    return fetch('URL')
    .then((res) => {
        return Promise.resolve(res.json());
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Fetch Error!!!", err);
    })
}
```

}